# How to replace 00 with Na excluding first row & first column using bash in comma separated file

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, gwas

I'm working with GWAS data, My data looks like this:

```
IID,kgp11004425,rs11274005,kgp183005,rs746410036,kgp7979600
1,00,AG,GT,AK,00
32,AG,GG,AA,00,AT
100,TT,AA,00,AG,AA       
3,GG,AG,00,GT,GG
```

Desired Output:

```
IID,kgp11004425,rs11274005,kgp183005,rs746410036,kgp7979600
1,N/A,AG,GT,AK,N/A
32,AG,GG,AA,N/A,AT
100,TT,AA,N/A,AG,AA       
3,GG,AG,N/A,GT,GG
```

Here I'm trying to replace "00" with "N/A", but since I have 00 in the first row & First Column (IID), the command I used:

```
sed '1!s~00~N/A~g' allSNIPsFinaldata.csv
```

The above command excludes the first row but not the first column as a result I got IID Values 100, 200, and 300 as 1N/A, 2N/A, and 3N/A. Can anyone please help "how to exclude the first row & First Column as well and perform the above operation. please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk '{$0=$0","; gsub(/,00,/,",N/A,"); sub(/,$/,"")} 1' file
IID,kgp11004425,rs11274005,kgp183005,rs746410036,kgp7979600
1,N/A,AG,GT,AK,N/A
32,AG,GG,AA,N/A,AT
100,TT,AA,N/A,AG,AA
3,GG,AG,N/A,GT,GG
```

The above assumes none of the column names on the first row will be the exact string `00`. If they can be then just tweak the above to:

```
awk 'NR>1{$0=$0","; gsub(/,00,/,",N/A,"); sub(/,$/,"")} 1' file
```

Comment: small correction here I have "00" in string format as snp value. can you please update the command

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples in GNU `awk` using its [`gensub`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function, please try following `awk` program.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
FNR==1{
  print
  next
}
{
  secondPart=gensub(/^[^,]*,(.*)/,"\\1","g")
  sub(/^00,/,"N/A,",secondPart)
  gsub(/,00,/,",N/A,",secondPart)
  sub(/,00$/,",N/A",secondPart)
  print $1 OFS secondPart
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the columns are separated by `space` characters such as whitespace
or tab character, would you please try:

```
sed -E '1!s~([[:space:]])00([[:space:]]|$)~\1N/A\2~g' allSNIPsFinaldata.csv
```

- The address `1!` skips the 1st row.
- The regex `([[:space:]])00([[:space:]]|$)` matches the `00` string
  preceded by a space character (it prevents to match the 1st
  column) and followed by a space character or the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

An awk:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","          # set field delimiters to a comma
}
FNR>1 {                 # process records after the first
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)  # iterate all fields (maybe start from 2nd?)
        if($i=="00")    # if field is 00
            $i="N/A"    # replace
}1' file                # output
```

Output:

```
IID,kgp11004425,rs11274005,kgp183005,rs746410036,kgp7979600
1,N/A,AG,GT,AK,N/A
32,AG,GG,AA,N/A,AT
100,TT,AA,N/A,AG,AA       
3,GG,AG,N/A,GT,GG
```

Comment: I tried the above command where I need to iterate from i=2. Since I have 2 Million Columns, when I'm running it is taking 1 hour to read and update each line. can you explain why

Comment: What can I say, it's a lot of data. I created a file with 2M columns and a 100 records, all fields `00`. My solution took 50 seconds to run (using GNU awk) where, for example, @EdMorton's solution, that you accepted, ran only 25 seconds - with the difference that his solution can't handle 2 or more consecutive `00`s so it runs in half the time. Maybe that's not an issue to you? Just try `echo 00,00,00,00,00,00 | awk '{...}'` (when testing, remove the first record limits `FNR>1` etc.).

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '1!{s/,00(,|$)/,N\/A\1/g;s//,N\/A\1/g}' file
```

If  not the first line and `,` followed by `00` followed by `,` or end-of-line, replace the `00` by `N/A` and other parts of the match remain unchanged.

This substitution is global but needs to be implemented twice because the patterns may overlap.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to repolace only 00 in other columns you have to add a delimiter (I am assuming space in my command) in your pattern:
`sed -i 's~ 00 ~ N/A ~g' allSNIPsFinaldata.csv`